# Algorithm to make all possible combinations of answers in a quiz

Tags: algorithm, logic, combinations

I have a personality test quiz where there are 8 questions and each question has 4 options.

The user has to select 8 answers finally(1 answer per question) and scores will be assigned to personalities based on the answers selected.

Now I have to find all the possible combinations of answers which is 4(options) ^ 8(questions) = 65536 possible combinations.

If the matrix format is like this

```
q11 q12 q13 q14 
q21 q22 q23 q24
q31 q32 q33 q34
....
q81 q82 q83 q84
```

I need an algorithm to make all possible combinations of answer selected and find out the personality scores for each combination obtained.

Help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Research first, *then* post your question; this problem has *many* solutions on line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

$all_option_combinations = getAllOptionCombinations(getAllOptionsData());
printAllCombinations($all_option_combinations);


function printAllCombinations($all_option_combinations){
    foreach($all_option_combinations as $each_combination){
        echo implode(" ",$each_combination).PHP_EOL;
    }
}

function getAllOptionsData(){
    $question_with_options = [];
    for($i = 1;$i < 9; $i++){
        $current_question_options = [];
        $current_question_options[] = 'q'.$i.'1';
        $current_question_options[] = 'q'.$i.'2';
        $current_question_options[] = 'q'.$i.'3';
        $current_question_options[] = 'q'.$i.'4';
        $question_with_options[] = $current_question_options;
    }

    return $question_with_options;
}

function getAllOptionCombinations($options_data){
    $current_combinations = array_map("returnAsArray",$options_data[0]);
    $options_size = count($options_data);

    for($i = 1;$i < $options_size; $i++){
        $next_combinations = [];
        $each_question_options_size = count($options_data[ $i ]);
        $current_combinations_size  = count($current_combinations);
        for($j = 0; $j < $current_combinations_size; $j++){
            for($k = 0; $k < $each_question_options_size; $k++){
                $combination = $current_combinations[ $j ];
                $combination[] = $options_data[ $i ][ $k ];
                $next_combinations[] = $combination;
            }          
        }
        $current_combinations = $next_combinations;
    }

    return $current_combinations;
}

function returnAsArray($each_value){
    return array($each_value);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q71 q81
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q71 q82
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q71 q83
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q71 q84
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q72 q81
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q72 q82
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q72 q83
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q72 q84
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q73 q81
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q73 q82
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q73 q83
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q73 q84
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q74 q81
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q74 q82
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q74 q83
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q61 q74 q84
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q62 q71 q81
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q62 q71 q82
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q62 q71 q83
q11 q21 q31 q41 q51 q62 q71 q84
....65516 more lines
```

- Since you haven't mentioned the language, I have used my choice of language, i.e, **PHP**.
- This code gets you all the required combinations.
- Now, you can just assign value to each option and calculate the final score for each combination. How you achieve that is an exercise I leave it to you(since you haven't shown your effort). Do let me know if you struggle in this too.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this (python):

```
ans1 = 1
ans2 = 3
ans3 = 1
ans4 = 2
ans5 = 4
ans6 = 1
ans7 = 2
ans8 = 3

score = ans1 +ans2 +ans3 +ans4 +ans5 +ans6 +ans7 +ans8

if score < 12:
    print("You are personality type 1")

if score >= 12 and score < 24:
    print("You are personality type 2")

...
```

This is a common way these type of tests get their results.

**EDIT**
This code will give you all the possible outcomes (answers from 1-4 for 8 questions). However it will take a whire to run and you have to make enough if statements to use it:

```
import itertools

def permute(LIST):
    length=len(LIST)
    if length <= 1:
        yield LIST
    else:
        for n in range(0,length):
             for end in permute( LIST[:n] + LIST[n+1:] ):
                 yield [ LIST[n] ] + end

for x in permute([1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]):
    print(x)
```

Comment: Where are the combinations?

Comment: The thing is there are a total of 16 personalities in which each scoring value equates to a personality type. Example: if the total score is 10 the personality might be a "diplomat". So I have to score all combination of answers and make sure that the 16 personalities are achieved at least once.

Comment: Added code to get combinations but I'm not sure if this is the right approach to the problem...

Comment: @HareiniSreethi I think the first part of the post will help you. The score will be from 8 to 32 in all cases, so you have 32-8=24 and 24/16=1.5. From 8 to 9.5 person has personality A, from 9.6 to 11.1 person has personality B and so on...

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand if for you is important to store this combination q14 q13 q12 q11, this is the pseudo code to create the sequance of your example

```
int columns=3;
int rows=7;
string matrix[7][4];
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
      matrix[i][j]="q"+(i+1)+(j+1);
   }
}
```

Comment: I need an algorithm that will find scores for all the 65,536 possible combinations of answers. The user will have to select 8 options (one for each question). I have added a comment above that describes what I want the algorithm to do @Prima Alessandro